# Why does my archived Swift app seem to look at the wrong path?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have XCode 10.2, and have tried Swift 4 & Swift 4.2. My desktop app runs fine from XCode, but crashes when I try to run it after archive.

I get this:

> Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing
>
> Application Specific Information: dyld: launch, loading dependent
>   libraries
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not found: _$SBOWV   Referenced from:
>   /Users/USER/Desktop/*/My
>   App.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib  in
>   /Users/USER/Desktop/*/My
>   App.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire

The weird thing I notice offhand is that it thinks my path is `/Users/USER/Desktop/*/Live Canvas.app/Contents/MacOS/My App`. That is certainly the wrong folder - I'm not sure if that's meant as a placeholder or it thinks that's my literal, incorrect path.

I also looked at [Xcode 10 Archived App Doesn't Run on Macs with Xcode 9 or Earlier Installed: DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452236/xcode-10-archived-app-doesnt-run-on-macs-with-xcode-9-or-earlier-installed-dyl) and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `Yes` for both `Project` and `Target`. The other question also doesn't appear to have path weirdness.

I should note that I have Swift 5 on my machine as well, however I'm on Mojave 10.14.4 so it shouldn't be an issue per https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1998?locale=en_US. It won't even let me install that because my OS is the right version.

Comment: What do you mean by *"My desktop app runs fine in emulator"*? There is no macOS emulator.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, I hit cmd+R to run the app from XCode - what's the right term there?

Comment: That actually runs your app on your Mac. No emulator involved.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452236/xcode-10-archived-app-doesnt-run-on-macs-with-xcode-9-or-earlier-installed-dyl

Comment: @matt I have that setting already marked to "yes" for my target. will update for project and try again

Comment: Same error from before. Will update question above

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from XCode 10.2 -> 10.1. Problem solved.

Comment: That is a workaround but I don't see how it answers the question. What we're looking for here are _causes_ and _solutions_. You're just avoiding the issue. If there is a bug in Xcode 10.2 it needs to be reported to Apple. If there isn't, you're doing something wrong and we need to know what it is.

Comment: Yeah I usually go back and report bugs and post here. I just need to get something out and then can come back to this. You are right though.